# TypeScript interface with XOR, {bar:string} xor {can:number}

Tags: typescript, interface, schema, xor, typescript2.0

How do I say that I want an interface to be one or the other, but not both or neither?

```
interface IFoo {
    bar: string /*^XOR^*/ can: number;
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use union types along with the [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) type to achieve this:

```
type IFoo = {
  bar: string; can?: never
} | {
  bar?: never; can: number
};


let val0: IFoo = { bar: "hello" } // OK only bar
let val1: IFoo = { can: 22 } // OK only can
let val2: IFoo = { bar: "hello",  can: 22 } // Error foo and can
let val3: IFoo = {  } // Error neither foo or can
```

Comment: Brilliant! I never realized `never` can be used to forbid a key from being present!

Comment: Great, that's what I was after. `+1` & accepted

Comment: @AT somehow its not accepted

Comment: @godblessstrawberry My bad! - Accepted.

Comment: This work and it shouldn't: `let val2: IFoo = { bar: "hello",  can: undefined }`

Answer (score 35):

As proposed in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14094), you can use [conditional types (introduced in Typescript 2.8)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) to write a XOR type:

```
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;
```

And you can use it like so:

```
type IFoo = XOR<{bar: string;}, {can: number}>;
let test: IFoo;
test = { bar: "test" } // OK
test = { can: 1 } // OK
test = { bar: "test",  can: 1 } // Error
test = {} // Error
```

Comment: Fancy..................................

Comment: What about `XOR<A | B | C | D>` for more than two type?

Comment: @trusktr I think it boilds down to [variadic generics](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1773) in combination with TS3.1. Unfortunately I have not come up with a solution for this myself yet. But I can think of using Head, Tail, HasTail and recursion as demonstrated here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/typescript-curry-ramda-types-f747e99744ab/. On the downside of things, this does not check on the permutation set and I do not know if that does collide with operations in set theory (such as triangle inequality).

Comment: You can solve this with the given `XOR` type by doing `XOR<A, XOR<B, XOR<C, D>>>` - just keep going to add more types.

Comment: Another suggestion I came up w/ before finding your amazing answer

```type Not<T> = {[key in keyof T ]?: never}; 
type XOR<A, B> = (A & Not<B>) | (Not<A> & B);```

I was trying to base myself on mathematical logic and the XOR formula

Comment: @trusktr you can use the npm lib [ts-xor](https://github.com/maninak/ts-xor) to perform XOR on more than one types e.g. `XOR<A, B, C, D>`

Answer (score 5):

You can get "one but not the other" with union and optional [void type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#void):

```
type IFoo = {bar: string; can?: void} | {bar?:void; can: number};
```

However, you have to use `--strictNullChecks` to prevent having neither.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
type Foo = {
    bar?: void;
    foo: string;
}

type Bar = {
    foo?: void;
    bar: number;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'void'
let foobar: FooBar = {
    foo: "1",
    bar: 1
}

// no errors
let foo = {
    foo: "1"
}
```