# "value" and "defaultValue" not to appear at the same time

Tags: typescript

I want "value" and "defaultValue" not to appear at the same time, but my code didn't reach the effect.

```js
type T = { 
    value: string;
    // other props
 } | { 
    defaultValue: string;
    // other props
 };
 let t: T = {value: '', defaultValue: ''}; // why can it appear at the same time
```

**Expected behavior:**

"value" and "defaultValue" not to appear at the same time.

**Actual behavior:**

"value" and "defaultValue" appear at the same time.

Comment: `type T = {value: string; defaultValue?: never} | {value?: never; defaultValue: string}`

Comment: The fact that excess property checking doesn't work for these is [considered a bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863)

Comment: And unions are inclusive, not exclusive.  So a value of type `A & B` is also a value of type `A | B`.  TypeScript doesn't have [negated types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) to officially represent exclusive unions (e.g., `(A & not B) | (B & not A)`) but you can simulate exclusive unions with mapped types.  For the particular case in your question its easier to do it manually as I did above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved with the XOR type, which you can  implement like this:

```
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never }

type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object
    ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T)
    : T | U
```

Then you would define your type T like this:

```
type OtherProps = {
    // other props 
}
type T = OtherProps & XOR<{ value: string }, { defaultValue: string }>
```

(stolen from [TypeScript interface with XOR, {bar:string} xor {can:number}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425344/typescript-interface-with-xor-barstring-xor-cannumber))

Comment: Could you define `Without`?  Otherwise this doesn't constitute an answer to the question.

Comment: oops. Edited :)