# How to make a type from the values of an union/intersection object type?

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I’m having a hard type figuring out how to define a type as the union of all possible values from a predefined object type.

Assume we have an autogenerated type `Person` that looks like this:

```js
type Person = {
  favouriteColor: string
  age: number
  female: boolean
}
```

How does one use the `Person` type to create a union type equal to `string | number | boolean`?

In my use case, the type `Person` is autogenerated. I’m using Ramda’s [map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) function on an object, to apply a function to each of the object’s values:

```js
import { map } from 'ramda'

classroom.people.forEach(person =>
  // Ramda’s `map` is applied to a `block` object here:
  map<Person, Person>(property => {
    // The type definitions for Ramda are not sufficiently strong to infer the type
    // of `property`, so it needs to be manually annotated.
    return someFunction(property)
  }, person)
)
```

The behavior I’m looking for is essentially equivalent to `keyof` — but as far as I know there is no `valueof` in TypeScript. What would an equivalent implementation look like?

Thank you very much!

---

**Edit:** ordinarily, the solution would be as suggested by @kaya3: `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]`. However, upon closer inspection, my situation seems to be troubled by the following:

```
type PersonCommonFields = {
  age: number,
  name: string
}
type PersonFragment =
  | { favouriteColor: string }
  | { female: boolean }
  | { eyeColor: Color }
  | { born: Date }
type Person = PersonCommonFields & PersonFragment
```

In this case, `ValueOf<Person>` as defined above returns `number | string`, i.e. only the values from `PersonCommonFields`, ignoring `PersonFragment`. The expected result for this example would be `number | string | boolean | Color | Date`.

Would there be an alternative approach to tackle this situation?

Many (many!) thanks in advance!

Comment: From this question - [Is there a \`valueof\` similar to \`keyof\` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49285864/is-there-a-valueof-similar-to-keyof-in-typescript) - you can do `type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the approach that I was using. However it did not seem to return the correct type if `T` itself is the union of different types — but I’ll look into it further if this definitely is the correct answer

Comment: If there's an issue with that `ValueOf` type when `T` is a union, I suggest editing the question to ask about that case. I believe `ValueOf` solves the case in the question where `T` is `Person`.

Comment: Thank you — done!

Comment: That looks better - just for the sake of it being a [mcve], could you write simple examples for `A` and `B`, and say what you want the result to be? I think I have a solution that should work, but it's best to get the question exact before answering, in case I'm misunderstanding it.

Comment: Thanks again, done again!

Comment: Turns out the idea I had doesn't work directly, but I think it should be possible. I'll have a think about it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]` type doesn't work how you want for union types, because `keyof` doesn't distribute over unions. For example, the type `keyof ({foo: 1} | {bar: 2})` is `never` instead of `'foo' | 'bar'`.

Instead, we can use a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which *does* distribute over unions (as its name implies).

```js
type ValueOfUnion<T> = T extends infer U ? U[keyof U] : never

type Test = ValueOfUnion<Person>
// Test = string | number | boolean | Color | Date
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAChBOBnA9gOwMLILZbQMQEsIAbAE0SgF4oBvAKCigEMBzCALilQFcsAjBABoGXJlg5REweAVQs6AXwDcdOqEhRMxZPCq0o8Tj35CoLI7wHxBUPhZO6Fq9dDhJ88VuNTAqIgD76AGZMAG7I3DLAEFo6nFIyclBOjIE0UEEQWEzEEnzIyLlMqMkB+hAgMYVxmtWOZen58KicACJM0ckqauCuCCgl1G4DmDj4RGQUAGSw-R5eED7dzr1QAGo53BAA8kEAqqgEaAA8ACoAfHqnUBAAHtGo5FCymbp7UAD8UHsA2gDWFWQQW+AF0oEYIKEECsNKcIFI9BtiFtdgcjqhjsM0Oc6AB6XFQOEI6gJWQsKCBYxWCm2ApFEqBWK6QLtaJ0IA)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you change the `|` to `&` in `PersonFragment` that it works (in other words, create a single type instead of a union type). It seems like you want these fields to be optional, could you use `Partial` with the single type (same behavior as just making each field optional)?

```
type PersonCommonFields = {
  age: number,
  name: string
}
type PersonFragment = Partial<{
  favouriteColor: string,
  female: boolean,
  eyeColor: Color,
  born: Date
}>
type Person = PersonCommonFields & PersonFragment;

type PersonTypes = Person[keyof Person]; // number | string | boolean | Color | Date
```

Edit:

@kaya3 noted in the comments that the current behavior is that at least one of the fields in `PersonFragment` should be set. If this is not a requirement, the above should work.

Let's say the requirement is actually that only 1 field exists, and not more? You can use the custom type `XOR`<sup>1</sup> to enforce this, and the resulting object will allow you to access the keys.

```
// Note: Define these in your global typings file so they can be reused
type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = T | U extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

type PersonFragment = XOR<
  { favouriteColor: string },
  XOR<{ female: boolean }, XOR<{ eyeColor: Color }, { born: Date }>>
>;
```

<sup>1</sup>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229857/522877

Comment: This isn't quite the same, since the original type requires at least one of the optional properties to be present.

Comment: The types that I start from are autogenerated (by `graphql-codegen`), so I would have to start from those as given...

Comment: Shoot, I glossed over that in your question. This answer might help someone else, but unfortunately, it seems like it won't be any help for you. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Wex’s answer I found a workaround, which isn’t perfect but sufficient for now.

`graphql-codegen` generates the following types:

```
type PersonCommonFields = {
  age: number,
  name: string
}
type A = { favoriteColor: string }
type B = { female: boolean }
type C = { eyeColor: Color }
type D = { born: Date }
type PersonFragment = A | B | C | D
```

From this I created `type Person = PersonCommonFields & PersonFragment` which is used in the code. Ideally, only this last type (`Person`) would be used to come up with a solution, because it doesn’t need to be kept up-to-date with `PersonFragment` as it evolves and includes more types in its union (`E`, `F`, `G` etc.) over time, as the GraphQL schema evolves.

But by rearranging a bit, we can get to this:

```
type PersonFields =
  | Person[keyof PersonCommonFields]
  | A[keyof A]
  | B[keyof B]
  | C[keyof C]
  | D[keyof D]
```

which creates the desired type `number | string | favoriteColor | boolean | Color | Date`.