# Generically Duplicating and Renaming Properties

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to take an existing type as the basis for a new type, which has the following goals:

- Contains original and renamed properties
- Either original or renamed property is required if the original is a required property (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37688318/typescript-interface-possible-to-make-one-or-the-other-properties-required))
- If original attribute is optional, renamed property is optional as well

I found a generic way to rename the properties already, but I have a hard time to figure out if there's a generic way to meet the other criteria.

Here's what I have:

```js
export type Postfix<K extends string, T extends string> = `${T}${K}`;
export type Postfixer<K, T extends string> = {
  [P in keyof K as Postfix<T, string & P>]: K[P];
};

type Foo = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
}

type DuplicatedAndRenamed = Postfixer<Foo, ".$">;

// works already
const foo: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  "three.$": 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}

// goal which should work
const shouldWork: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  three: 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}

// goal which should not work
const shouldNotWork: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  three: 'bar',
  "three.$": 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}
```

Wondering if that's possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution is a bit verbose. I am sure someone will find a shorter solution :)

```
export type Postfix<K extends string, T extends string> = `${T}${K}`;

type ExpandRecursively<T> = T extends object
  ? T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: ExpandRecursively<O[K]> } : never
  : T;

type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type Without<T, U> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, keyof U>]?: never };
type XOR<T, U> = (T | U) extends object ? (Without<T, U> & U) | (Without<U, T> & T) : T | U;

type Postfixer<T, K extends string> = ExpandRecursively<
  UnionToIntersection<
    {
      [P in keyof T]-?: [
        | XOR<{ [Key in Postfix<K, string & P>]: T[P] }, { [Key in P]: T[P] }>
        | (undefined extends T[P]
            ? { [Key in Postfix<K, string & P> | P]: undefined }
            : never)
      ];
    }[keyof T]
  >
>[any];

type Foo = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three?: string;
}

type DuplicatedAndRenamed = Postfixer<Foo, ".$">;
```

The goal here is to create a union of all possible key combinations that an object of type `DuplicatedAndRenamed` may have. The first two elements of the union would look like this:

```
{
    "one.$"?: undefined;
    one: string;
    "two.$"?: undefined;
    two: string;
    "three.$"?: undefined;
    three?: string | undefined;
} | {
    "one.$"?: undefined;
    one: string;
    "two.$"?: undefined;
    two: string;
    three?: undefined;
    "three.$": string | undefined;
} | ... 9 more ... | {
    ...;
}
```

As you can see, each element of the union specifies exactly which properties must be defined and which must be `undefined` for each possible case.

This implementation uses two handy utility types. `XOR` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53229857/8613630) will allow us to enforce that either the key with the postfix is allowed or the one without, but **not both**.

We also need `UnionToIntersection` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/8613630) to convert unions to intersections (as the name already implies).

For the implementation of `Postfixer` we map over the keys of `T`. For each key we create a tuple containing the `XOR`'d type of the key and postfixed key. If the key of `T` is optional we also add another element to the union where both keys are `undefined`.

```
| (undefined extends T[P]
  ? { [Key in Postfix<K, string & P> | P]: undefined }
  : never)
```

As you can see, the computed `XOR` type is wrapped inside a tuple. This will keep the `UnionToIntersection` from intersecting the `XOR`'d type.  After we intersected the unions of all the mapped keys, we only need to access the resulting indexed type with `[any]`.

Let's see if this passes all tests:

```
// works
const shouldWork1: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  "three.$": 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}

// works: mix of postfix and non-postfix
const shouldWork2: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  three: 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}

// works: three is not here because optional
const shouldWork3: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}

// Error: three and three.$ are not allowed together
const shouldNotWork: DuplicatedAndRenamed = {
  "one.$": 'foo',
  three: 'bar',
  "three.$": 'bar',
  "two.$": 'baz',
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZ2AMwJYA8A8BpKF3AQB2AJglEgE6pEDmANFACp4HFkXDV0B8UAvFAAGAEgDeTAL7jskoQG4AUItCQoAUXRgAhqQBKEAMYBXSglQA3CABsQmJn0Et8hUuTgAjAFZHgiqFAA-Mysrhw0yBCUUADy-gFBUGJQANq4NFAA1hAgcMixALoAXBpauiQGJmaWNnYxaQV8kvEBJUQQVpTxJUxKKuDQAKpEqHBETHAAkkSEZr6jRJiDjlAAFIOh7OS6IImrmSWDAJQCfBZwqCRQbR1RJy5ba-EHUBFRUJOKJ-xnFyTxwU+rSg7U6fVU0AA6qhgAALODGYD2RjLARJVIwV5EUqGazGEgQTDZXL5JiMYl5KDLAqBG6dKCSJQQqAADRiemRVJWLAAPlTNm4oJ4fIY-AFgqtoXCEUiyVyoAAyKknPmSmHwxFLRgORXMI7dEJ8wbggawRAoDBRTm4B6Cqg0WgrTQ6fRGUzmKy2TDxYYLCbTWYIeZjb0JJItBIpTEZCmkgoAWlpqQjYb5bI5yTSOSxZqQaCw2EY9roupgPGKzCjBQZjEz2GzGRgFaYVYZPBTCVVxlIEDQ7Suto4LabHbD4vRWd2jfN+ZwRa4DtLfD5TZK3YJfYgV2aY931xBt0o+t3BSUYckKVjzAK8XbPBSO1PymZADE4HA0WJ4mMICVi7QzygYAAHc4D-Bc6EAuFKAgCAk3-JRGWfU0ABFjDAaxUEMbRCBIABBV0iG0ABbLc0XgPNLUoTA3zgRgACIADoRHong+gAenYqBQMoTIEEUQwxiQCgNWsEhITgXiAEYSjQjCsJwrcCIqYgSLIwQvwCeif2Y+iSno5B33o+h4no6DYN0-SPG0ShjNMkC4EsqB6OsgAvOykMUTjuMkviSmIjAhXyMAZ0C8oQTGeMQso9ABKE4ARIRMSJN4gAmWT0Mw7DcOUgwiNIq4NNMnSWP0wy4DsgJzN-ZzrNskytIcpyXO0dyTM87yeL8oDYRg6BUHIIg4AS2EomgDwjG0YwgyFMBgAWbRrDiohhIQUTxN8gBmDL5OypTCLUwrwy0kq9Oc8rKucprStq1qPI4rj1EoShJJKaqoHC6rmI+mCIoSxbrDgYCyOAOBaAgOEomW1b1oAOWGlKXjkrLFPwg6Cs-Yr2mai6Gp6vqrJsy6zN6iybpa+r7NA5q3PuxQgA)

Comment: I am still not sure what causes the typescript playground links to be cut off sometimes :(

Comment: A mildly [shorter](https://tsplay.dev/NVZqGN) version, using a tuple of length 1 and getting rid of the `key` property by indexing into the result with `any`. It's probably also a good idea to include that you need to wrap the computed type so it isn't naked and gets lost when you use `UnionToIntersection`.

Comment: That is indeed more concise :)